# Programming flash in manufacturing environment using Codewarrior TAP

Tags: flash, programmer, manufacturing

I would like to use the [Codewarrior TAP](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/more-processors/dsp-dsc/codewarrior-tap:CW_TAP) to program flash on boards in a manufacturing environment.

My target is a P4080 CPU w/Flash memory. I am currently using an Abatron BDI-3000 for this, but [that device is now EOL](http://www.abatron.ch/products/bdi-family/bdi3000/) and I will eventually need to find another way to program the flash. It looks like the Codewarrior TAP can do it, but I can't find any solid clues for how to do this.

I suspect it can be done because some engineering folks in my org have used the "Codewarrior IDE" to program flash. **However, I would very much like to avoid using the IDE in a factory.** I know that I can telnet to the TAP, but there doesn't seem to be any analogous CLI commands to what I used on the BDI-3000. There's some words about the TAP having support for gdb, but I am not sure of the capabilities of gdb.

My tasks are very simple...

- **Erase some memory range**. BDI command was "erase 0xeff80000 0x20000 4"
- **Program a binary** from a tftp server. BDI command was "prog 0xeff80000
  /path/in/tftp/server/MyBinary.bin bin"
- **Verify the binary** was programmed correctly. BDI command was "verify
  0xeff80000 /path/in/tftp/server/MyBinary.bin bin"

The problem is I don't see the equivalent of any program, erase, or verify commands in the Codewarrior TAP manual. Moreover, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a TFTP server which contains binaries to write to the target. But if I need forget about TFTP and put the binaries on the host PC, that's OK too.

Can anyone help me get started with this? I just need to get pointed in the right direction. Alternatively, what other tools can I use to program this flash in a way that is automation/factory friendly?

Comment: Seems you way to go is here http://www.nxp.com/support/sales-and-support:SUPPORTHOME through *support request*. As Codewarrior is developed by NXP, and they also develop systems based on Freescale P4080, you have *one shop* situation and should be able to get information from the first hand.

Comment: @Anonymous, yeah, I think you're right. I had thought that since the all the BDI needs is a config file, that using the codewarrior TAP would just be a matter of somehow translating the BDI config data into something the TAP understands and then sending commands.

Answer (score -1):

You can startup the arm cross gdb, and run available python scripts for flashing.  You might need to modify startup configuration files, and maybe create your own XML file with details of your device.  You can copy/modify the XML File.

https://community.nxp.com/thread/473850

Comment: Also, we've had some some success using CodeWarrior Connection Server to load application to RAM, and run it.  The application programs the flash.

Comment: the P4080 is a Power architecture, not an ARM part.